# SSH Functionality of Ubuntu

Tags: ssh

In Ubuntu, when I try to connect to an SSH server from the terminal, a dialog window pops up asking me to enter my SSH password.  When I enter it, my password is remembered for the duration of that terminal session.  What settings / packages must be installed to achieve this functionality?  I'd like to get something similar working in a straight Debian install, so that I don't have to manually enter ssh-add everytime.  Thanks.

Comment: While using ssh you have to type the password everytime you try to connect the other way around is to generate public-private key pairs which enable passwordless login through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I think Seahorse takes care of remembering the keys.

Comment: Yep, seahorse acts as an ssh agent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I am unsure if you have made your keys first. This site may help there. http://kb.iu.edu/data/aews.html .

Afterwards you can use http://kb.iu.edu/data/aeww.html to setup the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.